# Managing files on VMs using PHP

Tags: php, file, virtual-machine, pydio

I have multiple Virtual Machines (VMs). One of them is a PHP Server, the others are just normal machines. How can I let the PHP server manage the files. And how can I implement access control to that too. I want the client to be able to control the files through a webpage. Just like say, Dropbox. Also, how can I allow specific users to see certain files, and others not. Meaning, User1 owns a file and shares it with User2 but not User3.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What do the other VMs have to do with the PHP Server? What files do you want to manage? What kind of access control? Are trying to create a Dropbox clone??

Comment: This question is over-broad... you're basically asking for an entire application design. You also don't provide enough details... what OS are you running? And you should look at keeping permissions in a database... (a cross table to link user ids to file ids to grant permissions) keeping all files out of the public root directory and allowing access to them only after checking the DB for permissions.

Comment: Ubuntu for the OS. Yes you can think of it as a dropbox clone. My problem is managing the VM files from the Php Server. SO if user1 logs-in, the server retrieves his files from his VM and show a file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking for a whole application design which is out of scope on SO. However, I'd recommend to avoid creating this from scratch. Instead use an open-source solution which you can customize later on according to your needs

Have a look are [Pydio](http://pyd.io) (formerly known as `AjaXplorer`)

And [here](https://demo.pyd.io/) is a demo provided by them

Comment: That's actually what I went with 2 years ago. We used AjaXplorer.